# Does image texture resolution impact rendering time?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying to make a high-res bump map for human skin. I've seen many examples where there was quite a lot of detail on the texture, although it's mostly in portraits. I've downloaded and open the OpenEXR file that have the [texture map](http://gl.ict.usc.edu/Research/DigitalEmily2/) included in it. The image resolution was at 8192 x 8192. Would such a size have an impact on rendering time, if so, does it vary by CPU/GPU? Also, will it affect the performance of the 'Texture Paint Mode' when the map is being painted directly on it?

Comment: Render time may be affected, but in theory it should not make a lot of difference, however it will have a significant impact in memory consumption. If you have little memory resources available for rendering this may have a more noticeble negative impact, like for example while GPU rendering on a card with low VRAM amount. Texture size will significantly affect painting performanceperformance

Comment: Done, posted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Render time will likely be affected, but not much so, in theory it should make a negligible difference unless you are working close to your hardware limits.

It will however have a significant impact in memory consumption. If you have little memory resources available for rendering this may have a more noticeable negative impact, like for example while GPU rendering on a card with low VRAM amount.

Texture size will significantly affect painting performance